# Why does IDLE continue to crash?

Tags: python

Idle keeps crashing and I can't figure it out. After restarting the computer and reinstalling Python, none of which seemed to work, I looked to my peers and was told to "install one of the Tcl/Tk". After getting another opinion I was also told that I already had this and found it to be true but decided to try it anyway since it continued to crash. Nothing has improved and I have an assignment due.

Any ideas on why this continues to happen and what I can do to fix the crash?

---

**Problem details**:

```
Process:         Python [1183]
Path:            /Applications/Python 3.3/IDLE.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      org.python.IDLE
Version:         3.3.0 (3.3.0)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [793]

Date/Time:       2012-11-05 14:10:54.124 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          181805 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           4
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  20 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   4
Anonymous UUID:                      68994A08-7FFB-4074-A553-CB60A60BB412

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error (1007) creating CGSWindow on line 263'
```

Comment: I have no experience using Python on a mac. But check the following link: http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/

Comment: What triggers the crash?  Just launching IDLE?  Or typing something or clicking on a particular menu item?

Comment: Just launching it. It crashes immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Tkinter inside of IDLE while on MacOSX with the python version that ships with OSX, then do not use it. Instead check out [this](http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/). Here is an excerpt:

Important

If you are using Mac OS X 10.8, 10.7 or 10.6, use IDLE or tkinter from a 64-bit/32-bit Python installer only with ActiveTcl 8.5 installed. If you cannot install ActiveTcl 8.5, use a 32-bit-only installer instead.

If you are using Mac OS X 10.6, do not use IDLE or Tkinter from the Apple-supplied Python 2.6.1 in Mac OS X 10.6. If possible, install and use a newer version of Python and of Tcl/Tk.

If you using ActiveTcl 8.5, there are some serious regressions with the ActiveTcl 8.5.12 and 8.5.12.1 releases, which can cause IDLE to crash. Until resolved, use ActiveTcl 8.5.11.1 instead. Read the details below.

Comment: BTW, that is from the link mentioned in the comments: http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/  You should always check there first for the most up-to-date information.

Answer (score 0):

For me, 90% of crashes were caused when I typed a left-parenthesis. That was fixed by:

In IDLE:

*Options Menu > Configure Extensions > CallTips > set to FALSE*

Then restart.

Took much research to find that super simple solution... the problem is caused not by an error in IDLE but by an error in the mac's Tcl/Tk code when calltips are called in external monitors above the default monitor.